# Use of combined comparison operators in Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

How does Excel evaluate combined comparison operators to return either true or false as shown in the image below? For example, the formula `=IF(4<5>6,"true","false")` evaluates to **true** and `=IF(4<5<6,"true","false")` evaluates to **false**.

[image]

Comment: Use AND function: `IF(AND(4<5, 5<6), "true", "false")`

Comment: @Akina I'm very familiar with the AND function, just wanted to know the logic behind the evaluation to produce such results. Thanks.

Comment: Thought I had an answer - was thinking it evaluates the first part 4<5 = True and then True < 6 = True, but the formula results in False.  Confused now.  The numeric value of True should be 1.  You could also get rid of the `IF` statement to use it:  `=4<5<6` will return FALSE.

Comment: *The numeric value of True should be 1.* 1 is the representation of boolean TRUE but not a value. Any boolean is greater than any numeric, TRUE is greater than FALSE - you may check this.

Comment: @Akina  fair point. `=True=1` returns False.  Never realised that.... guess I've never had the need to realise that. :)

Comment: *`=True=1` returns False.* Of course, I have pointed to the difference between the value and its representation and boolean to numeric comparing. Convert boolean to numeric then compare `=(True+0)=1` - and you'l obtain True.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A formula `x<y<z` is evaluated step by step, just like `x+y+z`.

Confusingly, Excel has the strange logic that `true` or even `false`
is greater than any numeric value (is there some philosophy here?) rather than being numerically equal to `1` or `0` as is more common. However, `=(4<5)+1` still equals `2`.

- `4<5<6` => `(4<5)<6` => `true<6` => `false`
- `4<5>6` => `(4<5)>6` => `true>6` => `true`
- `4>5>6` => `(4>5)>6` => `false>6` => `true`

and so on.

As has already been answered, you'd need `AND()` to evaluate multiple conditions at the same time.

Note that `=IF(condition,"true","false")` is actually redundant. `=condition` yields the same result (unless you need the string type).

Comment: I don’t know about this particular case, but *usually* the answer to “why does Excel do XYZ in a formula?” is almost always “because that’s how Lotus 1-2-3 did it”

Answer (score 2):

You can change the formulat to:

```
=IF(AND(4<5,4<6,5<6),"TRUE","FALSE")
=IF(AND(4<5,4<6,5>6),"TRUE","FALSE")
=IF(AND(4>5,4<6,5<6),"TRUE","FALSE")
=IF(AND(4>5,4>6,5>6),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

True and False can be used in a meaningful way, by "multiplying" them.

On a general level (in programming) one can use e.g:

> n=(n<6)*(n+1)
> ... will loop the values 0 to 6 as this is repeated, example below.

So to conclude; an expression with a conditional DOES evaluate to
to a "1" for true, *when used in a multiplication*, and "0" for false.

**That is:** a true 1 and 0 when using `(condition)*1` -> `1*True` => 1, `False*1` => 0

... so `(A1<5)*1` will give a `1` as result if A1 has a value which is less than 5.

---

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> n=0
>>> for i in range(20):
...   print(i,n)
...   n=(n<6)*(n+1)
... 
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 0
8 1
9 2
10 3
11 4
12 5
13 6
14 0
15 1
16 2
17 3
18 4
19 5
>>> 
>>> quit()

$
```

Comment: Excepting that Excel doesn't wok the same as Python and most other programming languages, so this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: The CONCEPT works the very same as in Python, please pick off your blinders. The Python snippet was to show what the effect is.